# Signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x7d02bdb8

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface, segmentation-fault

App is crashing at startup with signal 11 and sigsev.

Log from crash report

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'Xiaomi/santoni/santoni:7.1.2/N2G47H/V10.3.1.0.NAMMIXM:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
pid: 30404, tid: 30404, name: rg.etlegacy.app  >>> org.etlegacy.app <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x7d02bdb8
    x0   000000007d02bdb8  x1   0000007f7d0e6000  x2   0000000000001000  x3   0000000000000004
    x4   0000000000000000  x5   0000000000000040  x6   000000000000003f  x7   0000000000000000
    x8   0000007f8ef0cad0  x9   0000000000000001  x10  0000007f8ef0caa0  x11  0000000000000000
    x12  000000000000004e  x13  000000000000000c  x14  0000000000000001  x15  00334cb51f425b69
    x16  0000007f8d81d5a8  x17  0000007f8d7c894c  x18  0000007f836ebef4  x19  0000007f7d0e6000
    x20  000000007d02bdb8  x21  0000000000001000  x22  0000000000000001  x23  0000007f6ded2db0
    x24  0000000000000000  x25  3010888e20f53c95  x26  0000007f8b043a98  x27  3010888e20f53c95
    x28  0000000000000000  x29  0000007ff151f080  x30  0000007f8d7813bc
    sp   0000007ff151f050  pc   0000007f8d7810e8  pstate 0000000080000000

backtrace:
    #00 pc 00000000000210e8  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL11__dirname_rPKcPcm+36)
    #01 pc 00000000000213b8  /system/lib64/libc.so (dirname+88)
    #02 pc 0000000000133354  /data/app/org.etlegacy.app-1/lib/arm64/libetl.so (SDL_main+104)
    #03 pc 0000000000152a24  /data/app/org.etlegacy.app-1/lib/arm64/libetl.so (Java_org_etlegacy_app_SDLActivity_nativeSetupJNI+68)
    #04 pc 00000000000185cc  /data/app/org.etlegacy.app-1/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x17000)
```

Java_org_etlegacy_app_SDLActivity_nativeSetupJNI function

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_etlegacy_app_SDLActivity_nativeSetupJNI()
{
    Android_JNI_SetupThread();

    SDL_SetMainReady();

    /* Run the application code! */
    char *argv[2];
    argv[0] = SDL_strdup("./");
    // send r_fullscreen 0 with argv[1] because on fullscreen can cause some issues see: https://github.com/rafal1137/android-project/commit/d960cc244b17d8cc0d084f9c8dad9c1af4b2ba72#diff-b9bd293cfb066fe80c10d3fcdd0fd6cbL439
    argv[1] = 0;
    SDL_main(1, argv);

}
```

Should I move SDL_SetmainReady() to main() function?

Comment: The crash is in SDL_main, doing some sort of manipulation of a directory name (the crash is in dirname).  So my guess would be something wrong with your path argument.

Comment: @GabeSechan apparently changing function to SDL_GetBasePath() did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing function to SDL_GetBasePath() did the trick